# How to Move text file from Unity Asset folder to Android persistentDataPath at runtime?

Tags: c#, android, file, unity-game-engine

In my project i have my text file in asset folder, i want to move or copy the file to Android persistanceDatapath at Runtime.

My text file which store the bytes data, so i tried to read all the bytes and write it back to the persistancedatapath and from there i tried to read. But data was not coming properly.

So i decided to move or copy the file at runtime. Its works fine in the editor but not working in android.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/a.txt"));
fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "a.txt"), true);
```

this line works fine in my editor but after export to the android its not working.

When i tried the below condition in android device it didnt execute

```
if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/a.txt")))
            infotext.text = "PATH FIND IN THE RESOURCE FOLDER";
```

Can someone please help me how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have your file in assets folder or in STREAMING assets folder?

Comment: I kept it in streamingasset folder now. Tried to keep it Asset folder and resources folder also but its not reading.

Comment: I mean, you're trying to copy your file FROM streamingAssets TO persistent data path. Or FROM assets TO persistent data path? Becaues in your description seems the second, but the code showed seems the first one

Comment: any folder from asset its fine, i need to copy the file to the persistanceDatapath.
Actually i tried in both folder as well but didnt work.

Comment: FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "/assets", "a"));
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "a.txt"), true);



                                                                                                                                      

tried above lines still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UnityWebRequest` and `DownloadHandlerFile` to copy file from apk to data.

```cs
    string fileInData = Application.persistentDataPath + "/a.txt";
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    string fileInApk = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/a.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(fileInData))
    {
        var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(fileInApk);
        var download = new DownloadHandlerFile(fileInData);
        request.downloadHandler = download;
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    }
#endif
```